# Node.js synchronized audio streaming between server and clients?

Tags: node.js, audio, streaming, real-time

I am trying to build a web application that will **stream an audio** in the browser (without any plugins), with an ability to let other users join in to www.mysite.com and the audio will be streamed to every connected user simultaneously from the current audio position of the host (aka synchronized audio playing between server and clients).

What do I need to do implement something like that? I am working on a Node.js/Express project right now, but I haven't touched Stream or Buffer API. Is that what I would need to use? Also what about WebRTC? Is it applicable here?

Comment: I wrote a blog post regarding streaming audio in real time with NodeJS, it might have exactly the information you're looking for to get started: http://pedromtavares.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/streaming-audio-on-the-web-with-nodejs/

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [binaryjs](https://jster.net/library/binaryjs)

From their description:

> BinaryJS is a lightweight framework that utilizes websockets to send,
> stream, and pipe binary data bidirectionally between browser
> javascript and Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about WebRTC in similar use some time ago. It's one of solutions to create a WebRTC peer in server side node application. I've never done something like that, but check i.e. that question:

[Use node.js as a WebRTC peer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227143/use-node-js-as-a-webrtc-peer)

Comment: The application I have in mind for this is already using a webRTC connection. Would be very cool if I could get this feature set up.