# nodejs/express - play/stream MP3 but restrict download

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to build a media player similar to Soundcloud's, where you can stream the music but direct access to the MP3 is hidden and restricted to prevent song ripping.

How could I go about achieving this with nodejs/express?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714593/node-js-synchronized-audio-streaming-between-server-and-clients

Comment: This is great, thanks. I'm curious, however, do you think there is a way to do this without a stream server? Or is that an imperative component?

Comment: Maybe you can avoid it using websockets, for example socket.io, but I think that it would be a bit tricky